# Gauss-Markov Theorem Verification

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, least-squares

Can someone propose a simple test to verify Gauss-Markov theorem? Preferably, with Python.

It tried to generate sample of Ridge regression and OLS estimates for data generated from linear function with additive gaussian errors, but I got the same sample variance for them.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think the Gauss-Markov theorem needs validation by a computational experiment?

Comment: Asking for a demonstration doesn't imply disbelief in Gauss-Markov theorem :)